# Okta scim provisioning

Tags: okta, provisioning, scim

I have implemented the scim endpoints. But I don't know how to synchronization the scim endpoints in okta. Can any one help how we can do provisiong and what we need to provide for scim connector base URL and authentication details.

Comment: you should've started from Okta side, where it's all configured

Comment: The first step in delivering your SCIM integration is preparing a SCIM-compliant API server to host your SCIM service. Which nuget package you have used? In okta application integration first block you will have to enable scim ( not visible in case you are using ready made scim connector). Go to provisioning and configure and test your endpoints

Comment: https://github.com/FabianZoon/SCIM2/issues/4 
follow same nuget package , his implementation video , and issue which is created by me